# Angular Restangular on sortable, how to save?

Tags: angularjs, restangular, ng-sortable

I need to change the order of scope, save but me back an error that save() is not a function.

I'm using restangular to create the objects.

The function is triggered Onsort, I tried using http, but also gives me error.

```
$scope.onChange = function() {
        ApiRestangular.all($scope.section).getList($scope.query).then(function(res){
            $scope.items = res;

            order = ApiRestangular.copy(res);

            console.log(order);

            $scope.sortOptions = {
                animation   : 150,
                onSort: function(){
                    order.put().then(function(){
                        toast.msgToast($scope.section+ ' ...Ordem atualizada!');
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    };
```

Comment: Won't get much help without more specific details like what error is and how sorting is done

Comment: TypeError: $scope.items.save is not a function
http://localhost:8800/admin/app/controllers.js
Line 300